# IntelliJ Idea: How can I replicate these aesthetic comment blocks in the IntelliJ Idea onboarding tutorial process?

Tags: java, comments, organization

I like how these look compared to normal comments

A very minor thing, sorry for the trivial question

[Example of aesthetic comment blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrmuW.png)

I looked through the Appearance section of the Settings menu to no avail, and I'm guessing there might be some kind of extension I can download to replicate this

Answer (score 1):

Disable "Inlay hints" in the options.